# Rotating Sprite Object Directx9

Tags: c++, directx, sprite

I am making little game in C++ with Directx 9. I read some tutorial and i can draw my sprite object and move it etc.But i want to rotate it.I try :

```
void D3DGraphics::DrawSprite(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 &texture,ID3DXSprite* pSprite, D3DXVECTOR3* pos, D3DXVECTOR3* dim ){

pDevice->Clear( 0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_STENCIL,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0),0.0f,0 );

D3DXMATRIX matrix;
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matrix, 0.05f);

pSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);


    hresult= pSprite->SetTransform(&matrix);

    hresult= pSprite->Draw(texture, NULL, dim, pos, 0xFFFFFFFF);


pSprite->End();

}
```

When i remove settransform part, it works perfectly.I checked hresult s they returned S_OK.Any idea?

Comment: When i put settransform method, sprite is not even shown.

Comment: Can you try D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matrix, 0.0f); ?

Comment: it worked when angle is 0.0f.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is, that you try to use 3D-Transformations for a 2D usecase. Try to work with `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for the matrix. But there are additional problems. I presume the name dim stands for dimension, but this parameter of `Draw()`([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) sets the center of the sprite, not the size. Finally, a fullscreen-clear of your stencilbuffer without any use of it is unnecessary expensive, but I don't know your other code.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank for comment but there are 2 main question on my mind.First, my sprite object is 3D (ID3DXSprite*) even though its z-axis is 0.Second, my sprite is ball and i want to spin it just for test.Am i using right func.? 'D3DXMatrixTransformation2D' i used it, sprite was shown this time but nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why it doesn't rotate with `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D`. If you are working in 3D then you should pass additional flags at your `begin()` ([flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Maybe `D3DXSPRITE_BILLBOARD` will help you, but then you must call `SetWorldViewLH` or `SetWorldViewRH` first.

Comment: `D3DXVECTOR2 a = D3DXVECTOR2(5.0f, 0.0f) ;
 
D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&matrix, NULL,NULL,NULL,&a, 5.0f, NULL);`

When i did this, scene area is shifted upside but my problem is spinning ball.And  my game will be 2D but i did it with 3D objects, if i want do it with 2d object, what will need to use?

Comment: Okey i got this.It is rotating my scene (or my view i dont know correct word).So i need func. which rotate my sprite or my image or my ball.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the position of your ball to `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D` and leave it out at draw()? Like `hresult= pSprite->Draw(texture, NULL, D3DXVector3(texturewidth/2,textureheight/2,0), D3DXVector3(0,0,0), 0xFFFFFFFF);`. This should translate the ball after the rotation.

Comment: Thank you, i solved with D3DXMatrixTransformation2D. I just gave wrong parameter last time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not make sense to rotate the sprite, since a sprite is normally come with a 2d texture and used for bill-boarding, if you rotate it around X-axis, it's just like a picture flips around the X-axis, you can not get the effect you want, I have try to rotate it around the Z-axis, this works well since the texture was usually on the XOY plane.

if you want to make a spinning ball, why not use a 3D mesh? sprite is not a good choice for this request.

Comment: My game will be simple.So i think i dont need z axis?